# Representation of connected components in the $O(|E|)$ time/space variant of Karger's algorithm

Tags: algorithms, graphs, randomized-algorithms

I'm trying to understand the various optimizations given in the original [1992 paper on Karger's algorithm](http://people.csail.mit.edu/karger/Papers/mincut.ps). Specifically, looking at section "3.1 Unweighted Graphs", I don't understand what data structure is used to represent the variant of the algorithm that works in $O(|E|)$ time and space (the other variant, which uses union-find  and takes $O(|V|)$ space and $O(|E| \log |E|)$ time, makes sense).

Specifically: how would you represent the edges so that it is possible to

1. track the connected components induced by a sequence of $m$ edges in a random order in $O(m)$ time?
2. contract a sequence of $m/2$ edges in a random order in $O(m)$ time?

I must be missing something obvious, but I couldn't find any implementation for this variant (everyone seems mostly interested in implementing the union-find variant of the algorithm).

Comment: Doesn't Union-Find take $O(m \cdot \alpha(n))$?

Comment: You can ignore "random order", as the edges just are shuffled from the beginning.  For 1. you only need to check if the graph is connected, and that you can do in $O(m)$ time, right?